# Changing OpenSSL include path for qmake

Tags: openssl, qmake, dogecoin-api

I want to build Dogecoin with qmake. It doesn't work with Fedora's OpenSSL because its OpenSSL doesn't have elliptic curve cryptography included. So I've got my own OpenSSL but I can't figure out how to change the dogecoin-qt.pro file to include an OpenSSL from a different location.

Normally with make I would do this:

```
$ export OPENSSL_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/local/ssl/include"
$ export OPENSSL_LIB_PATH="/usr/local/ssl/lib"
```

qmake seems different, the file I need to change is here: https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/blob/master/dogecoin-qt.pro

How do I change it, or what arguments can I give to qmake so I don't have to?

Edit: I've edited the Makefile it generates but it would still be nice to know an answer because it will make nicer build instructions for other people.

Comment: Then why don't you update Fedora's OpenSSL?

Comment: Fedora's OpenSSL doesn't have ECC because of the possibility it infringes against patents. This might lead to be building my own rpm, but at this point I just want to get this application running. I cannot find a package by anyone else that does ECC and I did look first.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change variables defined for OpenSSL library

```
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/include
OPENSSL_LIB_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib
```

Unfortunately, you will also have to fix values for Boost, BerkleyDB and miniUPNPc as they link to a location specific for developer's machine.
On Unix-like system it's better to use pkg-config to get library dependencies:

```
unix {
    CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
    PKGCONFIG += boost 
}
```

Also it looks like at least miniupnpc and Berkley DB don't have any pkg-config configuration.