# How to implement OpenSSL in Qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ssl, openssl

Trying to use OpenSSL in my Qt project, here is my environment:

- OS: Win7 32bit
- Qt: Qt Creator 4.2.1 Community
- Qt Kit: Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_32bit2
- Openssl: Win32 OpenSSL v1.1.0e, downloaded form [this site](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)

I'm trying to `include <openssl/evp.h>` in my code, however, when I add `#include <openssl/evp.h>` in my main.cpp and build, Qt Creator shows the following error: `D:\QtProjects\dialogs\findfiles\main.cpp:50: error: C1083: 'openssl/evp.h':No such file or directory`

I have already followed the instructions in this question: [How to Include OpenSSL in a Qt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681012/how-to-include-openssl-in-a-qt-project)

My .pro file looks like:

```
QT += widgets

HEADERS       = window.h
SOURCES       = main.cpp \
                window.cpp

# install
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/widgets/dialogs/findfiles
INSTALLS += target

# for openssl - I added these 2 lines
LIBS += -LC:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib -llibcrypto
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include
```

Please help me fix this.

Comment: Does `C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include/openssl/evp.h` exist?

Comment: Yes, it exists.

Comment: wondering does my problem have something to do with me installing my Qt in D:Qt, instead of C:Qt...

Comment: That should not be the problem. Try changing `C:/xxx` to `C:\xxx`?

Comment: Changed the INCLUDEPATH from **C:/xxx** to **C:\xxx**, still error.

Comment: Try the Library Add Dialog. Right Click in your "makefile" and choose Add Library -> External Library. Maybe this adds more Information

Comment: [Add OpenSSL support for Linux Qt Application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47630402/608639), [How to Include OpenSSL in a Qt project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14681012/608639), [Changing OpenSSL include path for qmake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20592001/608639), [How to tell Qt to use different OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40429278/608639), [How to implement OpenSSL in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43384887/608639), [Is there any way to building static Qt with static OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20843180/608639), etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as an answer because iam pretty sure i figured it out.

You have to run Qmake before building, otherwise changes in your pro File will not be affected. Since Qmake is compiling your pro File into a makefile

*Build->Run QMake*

Worked for my OpenSSL library.

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, you figured it out! I can now use openssl in my Qt project. Thousand Thanks~